No "paint_mask" attribute in BMLayerAccessVert in Blender 4.2.1 LTS
I had a script for Blender 4.0 that set a mask in sculpting mode based on vertex groups
to set the mask I used the paint_mask attribute from BMLayerAccessVert
vertex_group_name = "..."
obj = bpy.context.object
if obj is None or obj.type != 'MESH':
    print("No valid mesh object selected.")
    return

# Get the vertex group by name
vgroup = obj.vertex_groups.get(vertex_group_name)
if vgroup is None:
    print(f"Vertex group '{vertex_group_name}' not found.")
    return

# Create an empty list to store vertex indices
vertex_indices = []

# Iterate over the vertices of the mesh
for vert in obj.data.vertices:
    for group in vert.groups:
        if group.group == vgroup.index:
            vertex_indices.append(vert.index)  # Add the vertex index to the list

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

mask_layer = bm.verts.layers.paint_mask.verify() # HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

mask_value = 1.0
for idx in np.array(vertex_indices, dtype=np.int64):
    bm.verts[idx][mask_layer] = mask_value

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)

But now in Blender 4.2.1 the BMLayerAccessVert no longer contains a field paint_mask.
What is the current way of applying the mask to an object?
I see in the documentation that it exists in version 4.0
https://docs.blender.org/api/4.0/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessVert
But it was removed in the latest LTS 4.1
https://docs.blender.org/api/4.1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessVert
What is the current way to be able to set masking on an object?
I can't find where this attribute was moved
